# How to make infopath controls mandatory based on another controls value in the infopath form using rules?

Tags: infopath

I have a drop down list in the infopath form and based on the selection(Only if aprticular value is selected ) in dropdown listbox need to make some of the controls as mandatory in the infopath form. This has to be done using rules. I am not planning to use any custom code in my form. How this can be achieved? Please Help !!

Comment: I would like more info on why this is considered off-topic. InfoPath is used to integrate with SharePoint and is specifically mentioned in the FAQ. This is an InfoPath question - where else to ask these questions if not the SharePoint stackexchange?

Comment: Agreed, This is very much ON Topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click Manage Rules to open the Rules interface. Click the cell that needs a rule. Click the New button and select Validation. Click the condition hyperlink and set it to your dropdown field is blank. Add a message into the screentip section and you'll be all set.

Comment: I need to make some of the controls in the form as mandatory, if a purticular value is selectde in the dropdown listbox. How can this be done?

Comment: You'd simply add them as additional options within the rule. If dropdown field equals x or dropdown field equals y show the validation rule.